# Can't find any way to read and print the preferred values from an excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I've an excel file in my local drive. I would like to read the data from that file using python in combination with `openpyxl`. So far I can only read any hardcoded Range. However, I can't find any way to read the value of `Range("A4")`, `Range("B4")`,`Range("C4") and`Range("D4")` individually using any loop and print them.

The values stored in an excel file like below:

```
Item    Cat     Fit          Hot
Black   Blue    White        Red
Easy    Hard    Moderate    Gentle
Max     Min     Del         Enter
First   Last    Discarded   Overestimated
```

If i try like this. I used harcoded number to specify a column.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('item.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb['Sheet1']
for row in sheet_ranges:
    item = ' '.join([cell.value for cell in row[:1]])
    print(item)
```

The result I'm getting (columnwise):

```
Item
Black
Easy
Max
First
```

I wish to get the values (rowwise):

```
Max Min Del Enter
```

It would be better if it was possible to specify the header and then parse it's values like a dictionary, as in `..DictReader()` in csv module. Thanks in advance for your kind response.

Comment: So are you looking to just get the values of A4,B4,C4,D4?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If you don't want to hard code the range, that's okay, but what criteria is supposed to tell your code how to retrieve that specific range? You'll need to hard code it one way or another (by range, row, column or the actual value), unless you have something like a config file that's separate from your code.  Without knowing your criteria it's hard to comment.

Comment: Please see the update to understand what i tried to mean in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I may be jumping the gun here but would this work:

```
In [38]: for row in sheet_ranges:
    ...:     for cell in row:
    ...:         if cell.row == 4:
    ...:             print(cell.value)
    ...:
Max
Min
Del
Enter
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I couldn't get rid of the hardcoded part, though.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('item.xlsx')['Sheet1']
for row in wb["A4":"D4"]:
    data = ' '.join([cell.value for cell in row])
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
Max Min Del Enter
```